# implementing BundleTypeAdapter in FUNF

Tags: android, bundle, gson

so i was looking to convert a bundle object to json using gson by implementing this [bundletypeadapter](http://code.google.com/p/funf-open-sensing-framework/source/browse/src/edu/mit/media/funf/json/BundleTypeAdapter.java?r=71115afe99f4696ef81f3209b3da37bd9aa4b626) that i found in the [FUNF project](http://code.google.com/p/funf-open-sensing-framework/).

my issue is that i'm not entirely sure how to properly implement that block of code. The only way that currently makes sense to me results in a circular dependency.

how you normally would implement a new TypeAdapter:

```
...
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Location.class, new LocationDeserializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Location.class, new LocationSerializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create(); 
...
```

or, what i would expect in this case:

```
...
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Bundle.class, new BundleTypeAdapter());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
...
```

my issue is that the only constructor that BundleTypeAdapter has is BundleTypeAdapter(Gson gson) and I'm not quite sure how to go about passing in an object that I have yet to create or instantiate...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson has a solution for the case you describe, [TypeAdapterFactory](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).  BundleTypeAdapter defines the needed factory for you in a static member variable called FACTORY.  To use it, call:

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(BundleTypeAdapter.FACTORY);
```

Comment: awesome. thank you :-)

after being unable to figure this out i've since moved on to using a hashmap instead of a bundle... but should what i'm doing now not work, I'll try your suggestion out.